# Variable assignment in which compiler phase

Tags: compilers

If I have a statement **int a=5**, in which phase will symbol table be updated with value of a (which is 5) ?

Different websites have different answers to it. In some of the websites it is written that assignment happens in **syntax analysis** phase and in others it is written that assignment happens in **semantic analysis** phase.

Which is correct?

Comment: Why do you think the symbol table is ever updated with the value of a?  I don't think  it's the job of the symbol table to hold values.  Are you asking about some kind of static analysis, e.g., constant propagation or constant folding?  Also it would help to edit the question to give us more information about the sources that say that.  Can you give us a quote with context, and a link to the source, for each of the claims?

Comment: If symbol table doesn't hold the values then where are the values stored and how are they retrieved during computation ?

Comment: @RajeshR The compiler's symbol table doesn't exist at run-time, i.e. when the code is actually running, so storing the value in the symbol table would be of no use "during computation".

Comment: So at run time how are the values fetched ? Like if c=a*b, how does run time know value of a if it is not stored.